# Writing to database in an android app

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

So far my project looks like this.

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.soultaker.myovertimesapplication;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View;

import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_add);
        Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_logs);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AddActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LogsActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblDate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvDate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <DatePicker
        android:layout_width="347dp"
        android:layout_height="96dp"
        android:id="@+id/dobPicker"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:calendarViewShown="false"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.61" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/addHoursText"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.39"
        android:hint="Εισάγετε Ώρες"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.EditText"
        android:layout_width="145dp"
        android:maxLength="2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Spinner
        android:spinnerMode="dialog"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:entries="@array/spinnerItems"
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:clipChildren="false"
        android:saveEnabled="true"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:foregroundGravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.6" />

    <Button
        android:text="Πίσω"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btn_back"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.02"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.96"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-smallcaps"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <Button
        android:text="Εισαγωγή"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btn_insert"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-smallcaps"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.96" />

    <Button
        android:text="Έξοδος"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.96"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-smallcaps"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textAllCaps="false" />

    <TextView
        android:text="Επιλέξτε Βάρδια:"
        android:layout_width="143dp"
        android:layout_height="28dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-smallcaps"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textAlignment="center" />

    <Button
        android:text="Αλλαγή Ημερομηνίας"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btnChangeDate"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.25"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-smallcaps"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textAllCaps="false" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**DatabaseHelper.java**

```
package com.example.soultaker.myovertimesapplication;

    /**
     * Created by Soultaker on 17/2/2017.
     */
    import android.content.ContentValues;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.database.SQLException;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
    import android.util.Log;

    public class DatabaseHandler {
        public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
        public static final String KEY_DATE = "date";
        public static final String KEY_SHIFT = "shift";
        public static final String KEY_HOURS = "hours";
        private static final String TAG = "DatabaseHandler";
        private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "MyDB";
        private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "Overtimes";
        private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
        private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
                "create table Overtimes (_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
                        + "date text not null, shift text not null, hours text not null);";
        private final Context context;
        private DatabaseHelper DBHelper;
        private SQLiteDatabase db;

        public DatabaseHandler(Context ctx)
        {
            this.context = ctx;
            DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
        }

        private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
        {
            DatabaseHelper(Context context)
            {
                super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
            {
                try {
                    db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
            {
                Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                        + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
                db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Overtimes");
                onCreate(db);
            }
        }


        //---opens the database---
        public DatabaseHandler open() throws SQLException
        {
            db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            return this;
        }


        //---closes the database---
        public void close()
        {
            DBHelper.close();
        }


        //---insert a Overtime into the database---
        public long insertOvertime(String date, String shift, Integer hours)
        {
            ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
            initialValues.put(KEY_DATE, date);
            initialValues.put(KEY_SHIFT, shift);
            initialValues.put(KEY_HOURS, hours);
            return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
        }


        //---deletes a particular Overtime---
        public boolean deleteOvertimes(long rowId)
        {
            return db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
        }


        //---retrieves all the Overtimes---
        public Cursor getAllOvertimes()
        {
            return db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_DATE, KEY_SHIFT, KEY_HOURS},
                    null, null, null, null, null);
        }


        //---retrieves a particular Overtimes---
        public Cursor getOvertime(long rowId) throws SQLException
        {
            Cursor mCursor =db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,
                            KEY_DATE, KEY_SHIFT, KEY_HOURS}, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null,
                    null, null, null, null);
            if (mCursor != null) {
                mCursor.moveToFirst();
            }
            return mCursor;
        }


        //---updates a Overtimes---
        public boolean updateOvertime(long rowId, String date, String shift, Integer hours)
        {
            ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
            args.put(KEY_DATE, date);
            args.put(KEY_SHIFT, shift);
            args.put(KEY_HOURS, hours);
            return db.update(DATABASE_TABLE, args, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
        }
    }
```

**AddActivity.java**

```
package com.example.soultaker.myovertimesapplication;

    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.DatePicker;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.Spinner;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;
    import java.util.Calendar;
    import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
    import android.app.Dialog;



    import static com.example.soultaker.myovertimesapplication.R.array.spinnerItems;


    public class AddActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        private TextView tvDisplayDate;
        private DatePicker dpResult;
        private Button btnChangeDate,btnback,btninset;

        private int year;
        private int month;
        private int day;

        static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID = 999;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_add);

            setCurrentDateOnView();
            addListenerOnButton();

            final Button btnback = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_back);
            final Button btninsert = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_insert);
            final Spinner shift = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
            final EditText hours = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.addHoursText);
            final DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(AddActivity.this);

            btninsert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    db.open();
db.insertOvertime(date.getText().toString(),//I CANT FIND A WAY TO GET DATE AS STRING AND PUT IT AS TEXT?//
                            shift.getItemAtPosition(spinnerItems).toString(),
                            hours.getText().toString());
                    db.close();
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Inserted",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

            //---Select All Overtimes---
            btnback.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(AddActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }

            });
        }

            // display current date
        public void setCurrentDateOnView() {

            tvDisplayDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDate);
            dpResult = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.dpResult);

            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

            // set current date into textview
            tvDisplayDate.setText(new StringBuilder()
                    // Month is 0 based, just add 1
                    .append(month + 1).append("-").append(day).append("-")
                    .append(year).append(" "));

            // set current date into datepicker
            dpResult.init(year, month, day, null);

        }

        public void addListenerOnButton() {

            btnChangeDate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnChangeDate);

            btnChangeDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);

                }

            });

        }

        @Override
        protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
            switch (id) {
                case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
                    // set date picker as current date
                    return new DatePickerDialog(this, datePickerListener,
                            year, month,day);
            }
            return null;
        }

        private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener datePickerListener
                = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

            // when dialog box is closed, below method will be called.
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedYear,
                                  int selectedMonth, int selectedDay) {
                year = selectedYear;
                month = selectedMonth;
                day = selectedDay;

                // set selected date into textview
                tvDisplayDate.setText(new StringBuilder().append(month + 1)
                        .append("-").append(day).append("-").append(year)
                        .append(" "));

                // set selected date into datepicker also
                dpResult.init(year, month, day, null);

            }
        };

    }
```

Well thanks to your advices i was able to go very far.Only one problem remains in wich i need your help.

Comment: please refer this repo. i have done sample for database  https://github.com/ananth10/DataBaseSample-Android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly you have a problem here: you are creating unused columns that does not exists in you table design!

```
db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME +" (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,NAME TEXT,SURNAME TEXT,MARKS INTEGER)");
```

you need to modify it to create a table contains all columns from COL_0 to COL_5 like this:

```
 db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME
                + "("
                + COL_0             +" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                + COL_1             + " TEXT, "
                + COL_2             + " TEXT, "
                + COL_3             + " TEXT, "
                + COL_4             + " TEXT, "
                + COL_5             + " TEXT "
                + ")"
        );
```

> I would like to know how to make that button

just add a Button to you xml and then bind it as follows: in `onCreate`

```
Button button = (Button) findValueById(R.id.YOUR_BUTTON_ID_IN_XML);
```

then set an `onClick` listener on this button as follows:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //call insert here to insert your data in database
            }
        });
```

> Do I need to make separate columns for day, month, year or i can store
>   them as one?

I would go for saving a date or even date and time in one column in the DB
this is to create a column called `date` as `TEXT`
and the instead of passing `String day,String month,String year` to insertData method, i will pass only one string date that is created as follows:

```
String date = day + "/" + month + "/" + year;
```

and save it in the column date!

> Also can i use datepicker without a setdate button
>   I don't recommend this as it could be a bad UX for users!

```
What am I missing?
```

I see that your `insertData` should work fine, and you can always post a new question if you have!

Comment: @KostasKoustoulidis does this solve your problem? if yes please accept as answer

Comment: No. Because when i posted someone edited my post and people who saw it couldnt understand what i was asking.

Comment: Edited.Thanks a lot.

Comment: @KostasKoustoulidis check the edit, and Please next time when you ask question you have to be more specific to a single problem or problems that needs short answers!

Comment: thank to your guidnes i was able to do many things.1 problem remains wich is here.**date.getText().toString()**

Comment: what is `date` that you are using? please check this statement from my Answer `String date = day + "/" + month + "/" + year;
` again

Comment: Its the key_day that i declared in handler.java

Comment: Man, please focus, you should pass a String value to `insertOvertime` method but instead you are trying to pass some Unknown variable `date` !

Comment: You should use something like my statement to create the String value that you will pass it to `insertOvertime` method

Comment: Thanks for all the help @AtefHares.I remade everything and started again step by step.Followed your suggestion and finally i made my app to write/read to/from database with only 1 input.Now i need to add Datepicker+Spinner but I'm getting errors.Would you like to help me again?

Comment: @KostasKoustoulidis glad i could help, but we can't continue discussion on the same question again as it's problem is solved, please instead accept this answer and then post a new question with your new work and your new problem details and I will of course be there to help if i can